# How to set UITextfield position during device orientation

Tags: ios, ipad, uitextfield

I have one image view on that image view i put two textField there. When i put device in portrait mode position on UITextfield is correct. Once i rotate my device position of UITextfiled change. Please help me.I am using IOS 6, Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to implement `-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration`
.
This method gets called when the device is rotated. Here you can set the frame of the `UITextField`.

Alternatively you can try to set the AutoresizingMask.

Comment: Hi @chris13 please explain more and give me some examples

Comment: If you want to know more about AutoreszingMasks have a look at this: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW5)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to implement it :
 1. Constraints ( adjusting from xcode->editor->pin)
 2. By pragmatically.

I personally suggest you to take a deep knowledge of this

[by Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can achieve this by AUTO LAYOUT (iOS6 new feature). Any new xib that you create in iOS6  will have Auto Layout activated by default. You have to adjust constraint. for this select your text field and image view. Now From Xcode’s Editor menu, select Pin. Pin your text field and image view.

for more about auto layout please read this awesome tutorial.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

1. You can also achieve this by pragmatically.

set frames for your text field and image in willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation

```
   - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 
                                     duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
   {
        [super willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

        if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
        ||  toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        {
            // set frame for your text field and image in landscape orientation.
        }
        else
        {
            // set frame for your text field and image in landscape orientation.
        }
   }
```

Thats It.